# Gtk inspector cant find part of widget

Tags: css, dialog, widget, styles, gtk3

I'm working on a Gtk3 theme using css. I want to style a dialog so I used gtkinspector to check what widgets are inside there. Works well, the inspector recognizes the dialog. But it is apparently unable to identify a border sitting around the dialog. (See image below).

[image: Border around dialog widget]

The border around the entire widget doesnt get hilighted by the inspector. .. so what does this consist of?

This is reflected in the css: if I put something like dialog * {green}  in the css, everything colors green, except for the border. If I put .background {green} then the border also colors green....

I tried to find 'padding' 'margin' and 'border' entries that could be causing the border, but cant seem to find any....Any ideas?

Comment: found a work around for now: put .background {green} and then *:not(dialog) {defaultcolor}...

Answer (score 1):

Without code or a glade file one can't say for sure which properties are being used to add that border.

The border itself isn't a widget but a GtkContainer property. So you must look to the parent, GtkDialog, for the correct properties being used. Most probably its the empty border around the container child (see [GtkContainer "border-width"](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkContainer.html#GtkContainer--border-width)) but could be alignment or padding.

If your goal is to change the color of the background color then you should change it via GtkDialog.

Comment: thnx for the pointers ! I'll test the container element. Hmm yes maybe I should simply download the source !